# CardElement not showing ui components in react app ie `Card Number, MM/YY, CVC?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, express

So my problem is that I cannot see the `CardElement` Ui component in the image below. It should be above the Order Total: $0 which is beside the payment method.
[image: React app with the error in it]

I have tried many other ways of debugging it but no luck. As of posting this, I am still debugging it and external help from experienced developers would be appreciated. I will provide my code below ie `Payment.js` `Payment.css` `App.js`

this is `Payment.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Payment.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import axios from "./axios";

function Payment() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // generate the special stripe secret which allows us to charge a customer
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        // Stripe expects the total in a currencies sub-units
        url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
      });
      setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
    };

    getClientSecret();
  }, [basket]);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // do all the fancy stripe stuff...
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        // paymentIntent = payment confirmation

        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY_BASKET",
        });
        navigate.replace("/orders");
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // Listen for changes in the CardElement
    // and display any errors as the customer types their card details
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  };

  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="payment__container">
        <h1>
          Checkout (<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>)
        </h1>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__address">
            <p>{user?.email}</p>
            <p>123 React Lane</p>
            <p>Los Angeles, CA</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__items">
            {basket.map((item) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                image={item.image}
                price={item.price}
                rating={item.rating}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__details">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <CardElement onChange={handleChange} />

              <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                <CurrencyFormat
                  renderText={(value) => <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>}
                  decimalScale={2}
                  value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                  displayType={"text"}
                  thousandSeparator={true}
                  prefix={"$"}
                />
                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                  <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

this is `Payment.css`

```
.payment {
  background-color: white;
}

.payment__container > h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: rgb(234, 237, 237);
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.payment__container > h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.payment__section {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.payment__title {
  flex: 0.2;
}

.payment__address,
.payment__items,
.payment__details {
  flex: 0.8;
}
```

this is `App.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Home from "./Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import Login from "./Login";
import Payment from "./Payment";
import { auth } from "./firebase.js";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  "pk_test_51Ku8iiSHAST6F5x2egU8YwHdYkqKAOcJIfrfXKa0b7kxeHm0ECkvFOLVW0KeaiudzfAfU31m954rOkIKGsoXhiAE00EQx04Did"
);

function App() {
  const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    // will only run once when the app component loads...
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      console.log("THE USER IS >>> ", authUser);

      if (authUser) {
        // the user just logged in / the user was logged in

        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser,
        });
      } else {
        // the user is logged out
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    //BEM
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={[<Login />]} />
          <Route path="/checkout" element={[<Header />, <Checkout />]} />
          <Route
            path="/payment"
            element={[
              <Header />,
              <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                <Payment />
              </Elements>,
            ]}
          />
          <Route path="/" element={[<Header />, <Home />]} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
//npm install <package-name> --legacy-peer-deps
```

this is Package.json of the src folder

```
{
  "name": "amazon-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.1",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.29.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3000 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

One last thing could anyone write why express is not working with node v.17 / 18 current version while writing this post it is express is not supported if I downgrade to node v16 will it cause trouble to other js code in my project. Please explain

package.json of the function folder

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0",
    "stripe": "^8.219.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

In some tutorial videos I can see they get it very quickly I don't know why I cannot debug. Kindly help me find the problem here. Thank you

Comment: I suggest you first use the CardElement component alone, see if it works. Currently you put loads of other things in there (router, checkout...) And we have plenty of online code editor, you can put your code in codesandbox for example, people can work on it immediately and even feed back to you with working code that you could see right away.

Comment: i have never used code sandbox before so let me see if it works I will let you know, but if I put cardelement component alone the project will meaningless,  so let me see how to use codesandbox for now. is there no other way to show its UI in my project

Comment: Actually, it's one of the way to debug the issue. Let it be alone meaning checking whether you're setting it up correctly. If it does work, then something that you build around interfere it, the problem then shift to that surround things, not the card component

Comment: alright i will try to see to it

Answer (score 0):

In your `App.js` file, where you declare your `Route` to `/payment`, try to pass a single component, instead of passing your component already wrapped in `<Elements>` component. 
I've faced this problem and for some reason, Stripe elements won't work that way. So instead try to make a component that will render your `Payment` component wrapped in `<Elements>`, I'll write some pseudocode for you: 
`ParentComponent.js`

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Elements>
            <Payments />
        </Elements>
    );
}
```

So now, you would just do this in your `App.js` component:

`App.js`

```
<Route
    path="/payment"
    element={[
        <Header />,
        <ParentComponent />
    ]}
/>
```

Comment: So you are saying I should make a different component like example .js and write the pseudocode in it and call it in app.js  and that's how it should work. I have understood in this way is it correct

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Also, don't forget to pass stripePromise as prop to your new component

Comment: i have tried your method but alas its not working I have  made new component but I still not showing.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find a proper solution.
Older versions of stripe/react-stripe-js are not working with react18. To solve issue, please install latest version of react-stripe-js.

npm install stripe/react-stripe-js@latest

Worked for me.

Comment: So you are saying other things such as wrapping of the element in payment is correct for me. The only thing is the version problem, so were you able to see card no. CVC, mm/yy, etc in it.